# How can I iterate over the contents of a directory in unix without using a wildcard?

Tags: bash, unix, wildcard

I totally understand what the problem is here.

I have a set of files, prepended as 'cat.jpg' and 'dog.jpg.'  I just want to move the 'cat.jpg' files into a directory called 'cat.' Same with the 'dog.jpg' files.

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    name=`echo "$f"|sed 's/ -.*//'`
    firstThreeLetters=`echo "$name"|cut -c 1-3`
    dir="path/$firstThreeLetters"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

I get this message:

`mv: cannot stat '*.jpg': No such file or directory`

That's fine.  But I can't find any way to iterate over these images without using that wildcard.

I don't want to use the wildcard. The only files are prepended with the 'dog' or 'cat'. I don't need to match. All the files are .jpgs.

Can't I just iterate over the contents of the directory without using a wildcard?  I know this is a bit of an XY Problem but still I would like to learn this.

Comment: That error message indicates that there are no .jpg files in the current directory. Are you in the right directory when you run this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.jpg` would yield the literal `*.jpg` when there are no matching files. 
Looks like you need `nullglob`. With Bash, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob                # makes glob expand to nothing in case there are no matching files
for f in cat*.jpg dog*.jpg; do   # pick only cat & dog files
  first3=${f:0:3}                # grab first 3 characters of filename
  [[ -d "$first3" ]] || continue # skip if there is no such dir
  mv "$f" "$first3/$f"           # move
done
```

Comment: "Your issue is not the wildcard, but the fact that it is too inclusive." Why? All I have are jpgs in the directory. No hidden files...what am I including?

Comment: `*.jpg` would match all jpg files while you just wanted the ones that start with `cat` or `dog`.

Comment: Fortunately for me, the only files in the directory are prepended with the 'dog' or 'cat'. I don't need to match...all the files are .jpgs! This isn't the problem. I think the problem has to do with using the wildcard symbol by the time I get to `mv "$f" "$dir"`